# Mailchimp Landing Pages seem broken

Tags: mailchimp

I made some Mailchimp Landing pages a while back using strictly the in-band tools (no fancy API stuff) in the most straightforward way.  They all worked when they were created. Now they don't work.  A Mailchimp branded "sticker" that I don't remember seeing before appears to be slapped on top of the form in an inopportune place. The sticker has links to mailchimp privacy policy terms and general Mailchimp signup.  You can enter an email address in the email field.  The other field IIRC is optional but you can't enter anything in it now.  And the submit button doesn't do anything.  Nothing appears to be wrong in the mailchimp landing page editor.   All of the client's landing pages fail the same way and they all worked when they were originally made. [Here is an example page](https://mailchi.mp/c40b3693258d/thing-from-mar-a-lago):  I hope I have asked this question the right way but please forgive me if I did something wrong in the asking.

Comment: https://mailchimp.com/help/mailchimp-support-options/

Comment: free account, no support.  But I solved it the way you solve some system problems. REBOOT.   I unpublished the landing pages and republished them without changing anything else.  Bingo I was able to submit the data.  Go figure.